# Attachments and data sending through REST API by clicking custom button

Tags: salesforce

How to send attachments in different formats in an opportunity & related information via REST API callouts by clicking a custom button?

Comment: Please add your code that you have tried and where you stuck. Please learn [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your button would call into a controller that would make a callout